# What IANA timezone to use for CDT?

Tags: javascript, timezone, momentjs

I have a time stored in UTC: 2023-03-13T20:40:54.358Z

This time corresponds to my local time (CDT) of 3:40PM.

I am attempting to display this on a web browser in CDT using momentjs. I haven't been able to find a definitive answer to which IANA timezone corresponds to CDT. "America/Chicago" seems to be popular, but that shows 2:40PM, which is CST. Which IANA timezone should I use for CDT?

For example:

```
moment.tz("2023-03-13T20:40:54.358Z", "America/Chicago").format()
```

outputs "2023-03-13T14:40:54-06:00", which is CST. But I want it to output "2023-03-13T15:40:54-05:00", which is CDT. Which IANA timezone should I use instead of "America/Chicago"? Or, is there something else I need to do to "turn on" DST in momentjs?

Comment: It outputs as expected for me `2023-03-13T15:40:54-05:00` [sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/cranky-cohen-z1ztw8?file=/src/index.js)

Comment: So are you saying moment.tz("2023-03-13T20:40:54.358Z", "America/Chicago").format(), outputs "2023-03-13T15:40:54-05:00"? and not "2023-03-13T14:40:54-06:00"?

Comment: Yes, I've added a sandbox link.

Comment: Yeah that's just odd. In you sandbox it shows correct. But in my browser it shows incorrect. Maybe it's a browser setting.

Comment: you're definitely using the current `moment-timezone` package?

Comment: Well, wouldn't you know it, that was the issue. Apparently I was using an older version, and something must have been different with it. I upgraded to the latest, and it is working fine now.

Answer (score -1):

The IANA time zone ID `America/Chicago` represents *the time in Chicago*.

- It uses UTC-6 when daylight saving time is not in effect, which is called Central Standard Time (CST)
- It uses UTC-5 when daylight saving time is in effect, which is called Central Daylight Time (CDT)

There is not a unique identifier for `CDT` by itself, because that's not how time zones work.  A time zone identifies a region that operates by the same *set* of timekeeping policies, including standard time, daylight time, and the dates and times of the transitions between them.

The sample code you showed is correct, and should emit the result having UTC-5, because DST is in effect for that date and time.

In comments you mentioned that you are seeing correct results from a Node.JS sandbox, but not in the browser.  Likely you are not loading time zone data correctly for the browser environment.  Per [the docs](https://momentjs.com/timezone/docs/#/use-it/browser/), You need to have both Moment, and Moment-Timezone, and should use one of the "with data" files, such as:

```html
<script src="moment.js"></script>
<script src="moment-timezone-with-data.js"></script>
```

If you only need relatively current data, use the `moment-timezone-with-data-10-year-range.min.js` file, which is listed [here](https://momentjs.com/timezone/).

Also, you might consider upgrading to [Luxon](https://moment.github.io/luxon/#/), which does not require any time zone data files since it uses the data provided by `Intl`.